# How can i get my button to align in the center?

Tags: html, css

I made some cards and i want to center the button. The only thing is, whatever I do the button stays at the start. And when i display the button as a flex or a block, it expands to full width. Can someone help me out?
The H3 does perfectly align in the center. I can't figure out why the button stays at exactly the same spot.

```css
.index-cards .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.index-cards .card {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.index-cards .card-image {
  height: 240px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.index-cards .card-1 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=1);
}

.index-cards .card-2 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=2);
}

.index-cards .card-3 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=3);
}

.index-cards p {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.index-cards h3,
.index-cards a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="index-cards my-150px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-1"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Sportscholen</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Sportschool zoeken</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-2"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Nieuw bij FP30</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Eerste keer</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-3"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Contact</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Contact opnemen</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new class `text-center` and wrapped the `<a>` inside this new `div`. The reason the heading was centering but not the anchor. Because on heading is CSS `display: block;` is applied by default and taking the full width.

```css
.index-cards .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.index-cards .card {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.index-cards .card-image {
  height: 240px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.index-cards .card-1 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=1);
}

.index-cards .card-2 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=2);
}

.index-cards .card-3 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/500&text=3);
}

.index-cards p {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.index-cards h3,
.index-cards a {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-center{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="index-cards my-150px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-1"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Sportscholen</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
      <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Sportschool zoeken</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-2"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Nieuw bij FP30</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
       <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Eerste keer</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image card-3"></div>
      <h3 class="my-30px">Contact</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, dignissimos! Autem fugit perspiciatis incidunt nulla expedita quaerat cupiditate neque iure!</p>
       <div class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn my-30px">Contact opnemen</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **.index-cards a** add separately

```
.index-cards h3,
.index-cards a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Add This:

```
.index-cards a {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: This will add a link to the empty space as well. Kind of on the whole <a> row

Comment: who just needs the link to the center?